# Adding event listeners by loop vs adding to document and checking if event target matches element

Tags: javascript, loops, addeventlistener

Is there any benefit of using one of these methods over the other?

Method 1 :

Looping through each element and adding event listener

```
const classes = document.getElementsByClassName("class");

for (let i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
  classes[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    console.log(classes[i]);
  });
}
```

Method 2 : Add event listener to document and check if event target matches element

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (event.target.matches(".class")) {
    console.log(event.target);
  }
});
```

Comment: They don't do the same. If in the first case one of the elements looses its class, they will still trigger the listener while the first one won't. If new elements win this class after you did attach the events, they won't trigger in the first case while the second one will catch it.

Comment: @Kaiido Which one would you recommend using, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Depends on your use case. We can't answer that for you, but generally if you can delegation (the second) is easier to maintain and slightly better for perfs. However, if you need something like `MouseEvent.offsetX`, then delegating can't give it to you, (though you could still calculate it yourself).